# Istio-proxy did not receive request from host

Tags: istio

I have an express js client app and an express server app with almost the same istio configuration. Client cannot be accessed through its host URL while the server is working well. Curl client host URL just gives me infinite waiting. And I cannot find any related traffic log in the istio-proxy of client pod. This is very confusing. What could be the possible reason for this problem?

istioctl analyse on live cluster dose not give any helpful information